# Is hard tap water useful for "salting out" a liquid organic solute?

Tags: organic-chemistry, precipitation

We use methylene iodide ("MI", CH2I2) as a heavy liquid for sink-swim mineral separation. We use acetone to wash the MI off of the minerals and glassware after we're done. MI is pretty expensive, so we save that MI/acetone mix to later recover the MI. This is done by adding lots of water to the mix. The solution starts off very cloudy, but with enough water (probably something like a 10:1 water-acetone ratio), the solution become clear, and a well-defined blob of MI is present at the bottom of the container.

My question is if it is better to use deionized water for this, or if it's better to use hard tap water that's high in calcium bicarbonate? I thought the hard tap water might actually be better for this, because of all the dissolved ions interacting with the water, limiting the space for MI to stay dissolved to the water and acetone, similar to a "salting out" precipitation reaction.

Comment: It may depend on the composition of the organic and of the inorganic phases. What are the metallic ions in solution ? And in which concentration ? Are they complexed by EDTA or similar agents ?

Comment: Why don't you just vacuum distill it? Like why add contamination to it? Pull a vacuum on it, the acetone is pretty cheap so even if it gets wasted yeah who cares and then just distill the Di iodo methane?

Comment: @PulkitSharma You mean just forego the water all together? Just try to evaporate out the acetone, leaving the MI behind? I hadn't thought of this because I was always told that MI was actually fairly volatile, despite it being a heavy liquid. https://haz-map.com/Agents/8547 That says its vapor pressure is only 1.2 mm Hg, though.

Comment: Somewhat irrelevant note: *sea water* was used for photo processing aboard ship in WWII: https://www.pbagalleries.com/m/lot-details/index/catalog/542/lot/177698/Archive-of-World-War-II-Photo-Technical-School-Papers , IF#52-7 Sensitized Materials - Sea Water Processing. 1943 . However, this was useful because it removed unexposed silver halides, rather than for salting out ;-)

Comment: No I mean distill iut the MI. pull a vacuum of 5mm and purify that fucker before next use too